# What would be the easiest way to retopo this object?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

i made some kinetic balls (newton's cradle) in blender, and used a decimate modifier to reduce polycount. the topology is a bit ugly, as seen in the photo bellow:

[image]

i want them all to be quads, is there a way to do that easily (besides CNTRL=F=tris to quads) i want some better topology as seen in this photo:

[image]

see how they are all quads? i want that, but for my model.

Comment: Revert to before using the *Decimate* modifier, I assume it had better topology previously

Comment: yeah, but i need to reduce polycount, and i am most comfortable with decimate modifier

Comment: How does it look in object mode with smooth shading? It may look ugly on the image you posted here, but if it looks OK when rendered, is there really any reason to worry?

Comment: it looks good in object mode, but i might be selling the model, so i will be showing wireframe view.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a different approach to modeling your Newtons Cradle. It could be as simple as this...

Add a plane with four vertices and extrude it out and down to form the base (12 Verts). The balls could be UV Spheres(114 verts). Add a circle with 16 verts extrude it up and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to create the radius repeat to finish it (352 Verts). Of course you can use different numbers.

[image]

Comment: please provide a more detailed answer, it is very unclear what you are getting at.

Comment: @Optimus That is the cleanest possible topology for such simple object

Comment: my model has triangulated faces that i want to be quads. unless your talking about the answer above..then......

Comment: @Dontwalk i am asking whats the easiest way to retopologize my model, not remake it.

Comment: @Optimus - I don't believe you can. Your model is a mess.

Comment: @Dontwalk which is exactly why i am here..i find it hard to believe i can't retopologize it.

Comment: The point is you *can* retopologize it. By hand. Which ends up being more work than just modelling it cleanly from scratch

Comment: If you are lazy, try [Instant Meshes](https://github.com/wjakob/instant-meshes) @Optimus

Comment: The "easiest way to re-topo"? Not having to re-topo at all! Use proper topology in the first place. Topology is your object, it is not something to be dealt with, or fixed "later".

Comment: @p20r i did, gave me bad results.